# Loading Square on the border of image using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thank you for reading this I want a square which will load in 2 seconds around a image of 50x50

Loading Square image:
[image]

From above image the middle one is a image of height=50 and width=50, and the red colour border is loading square .

whenever anyone hover on that image that red colour square will start loading around the image and after 2 second it will complete

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: Yes Sir I will update it very soon

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SVG` and animate a path around an inner image, e.g.

The direction of the effect is dependent on how you build the `path`

```css
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/qdngFNL/Screenshot-2019-06-07-at-11-45-55.png) center no-repeat / 50px 50px;
}

svg:hover path {
  animation: dash 2s linear 0s forwards; 
}

svg path {
   stroke-dasharray: 770;
   stroke-dashoffset: 770;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <path d="M2 12L2 188 Q 2,198 20,198 L 188 198 Q198,198 198,188 L198 12 Q198,2 188,2 L12 2 Q2,2 2,12z" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Also, for the sake of accessibility remember to add an `aria-label`/`aria-describedby` attribute if you need to convey useful information to the user, otherwise add a `role="none"` (or "`presentation`") to hide this element from assistive tecnologies.

Comment: @SantoshKumar you're welcome: feel free to accept the answer